# Joining tables with slug and id in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am very very new to Laravel and am trying to learn how to code in it the way you're supposed to.

I have two tables, a `user` table and a `profiles` table, when you load a profile, it also fetches data from the user table based on that profile. It uses the slug to load the profile.

As I am trying to learn Laravel and trying to learn to build queries I am wondering is the following possible with one query using a join? If so how do I do it?

```
public function index($slug)
{
    $profile_data = Profile::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    $user_data = User::where('id',$profile_data->user_id)->first();
    return view('profile',['profile' => $profile_data, 'user' => $user_data]);
}
```

Comment: Might be helpful: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one query using following code

```
$data = Profile::leftJoin('user_table', 'user_id', 'user_table.id')
->where('slug',$slug)->first()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the slug to identify the profile is that, the slug depends on profile data which may change. As a result, shared links to the profile may fail, if the user edits the data used to generate the slug, after sharing the link.

A better way will be to use an identifier that is not likely to change, like a unique user ID. You can then attach the slug as an optional parameter to the link:

```
mydomain.com/users/5994/john-doe
```

With 5994 as the user ID and john-doe as the slug component.